# Changing JS code from clicking image to clicking link

Tags: javascript

I found the following JS online, which functions like:

If an image is clicked, open the image in new window and prompt for print. Once printed the window closes. I need this script modified to click a print link it prints an image then closes the new image window. So I want to change from clicking the image itself to clicking a link that says print image.

Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

function makepage(src)
{
  // We break the closing script tag in half to prevent
  // the HTML parser from seeing it as a part of
  // the *main* page.

  return "<html>\n" +
    "<head>\n" +
    "<title>Temporary Printing Window</title>\n" +
    "<script>\n" +
    "function step1() {\n" +
    "  setTimeout('step2()', 10);\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "function step2() {\n" +
    "  window.print();\n" +
    "  window.close();\n" +
    "}\n" +
    "</scr" + "ipt>\n" +
    "</head>\n" +
    "<body onLoad='step1()'>\n" +
    "<img src='" + src + "'/>\n" +
    "</body>\n" +
    "</html>\n";
}

function printme(evt)
{
  if (!evt) {
    // Old IE
    evt = window.event;
  }    
  var image = evt.target;
  if (!image) {
    // Old IE
    image = window.event.srcElement;
  }
  src = image.src;
  link = "about:blank";
  var pw = window.open(link, "_new");
  pw.document.open();
  pw.document.write(makepage(src));
  pw.document.close();
}

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

---

```
<img src="fortune.jpg" onclick="printme(event)" />
```

I do not know any JS so I apologize. I only do php/mysql. 
Best Regards!
Jim.

Comment: I don't see printme() being called anywhere.

Comment: @Jim: That is the declaration of the function, it is not called. Where is `printme` called?

Comment: Felix, I tried changing the     "<img src='" + src + "'/>\n" +
 to     "<img src='" + href + "'/>\n" + but it didn't do anything. 
I also attempted modifying src = image.src;
to src = a.href; but it also did nothing.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include my img src code. thats where print me is... I've added it below the js now.

Comment: When you swap an image with a link, what should be printed?

Comment: I want it to print the linked image. < a href="image.jpg" onclick="printme(event)">Print Image</a> but its not working

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="someurl.jpg" id="imgid' />
<a href="javascript:printme('imgid');">Print the image</a>

function printme(id)
{    
  var src = document.getElementById(id).src;
  var link = "about:blank";
  var pw = window.open(link, "_new");
  pw.document.open();
  pw.document.write(makepage(src));
  pw.document.close();
}
```

In the old method, the `printme` function knows what image should be printed: the same image that was clicked; when you change the trigger, you need to tell the function explicitly what image you want to print. That is why we are adding an `id` to the image and pass it to `printme` function. But if you only have *one* image on the page, or if a *spacial* relation exists (like the link always being the immediate next node after the image), then we can do it differently and need no `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your link looks like, but assuming it's just a plain anchor:

Change from:

```
<img src="fortune.jpg" onclick="printme(event)" />
```

To:

```
<img id="printableImage" src="fortune.jpg" onclick="printme(event)" />
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="printme('printableImage')" />
```

Then alter the printme() function to retrieve the image src from the passed in image element id (jQuery makes this easy):

```
function printme(printableImageId)
{
  var src = $('#' + printableImageId).attr('src');
  // the rest of the logic...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to modify the printMe function a bit, doing this should fix it:

```
function printme(evt)
{
    if (!evt) {
        // Old IE
        evt = window.event;
    }    
    var anchor = evt.target;
    if (!anchor) {
        // Old IE
        anchor = window.event.srcElement;
    }
    src = anchor.href;
    link = "about:blank";
    var pw = window.open(link, "_new");
    pw.document.open();
    pw.document.write(makepage(src));
    pw.document.close();
    return false;
}
```

And then on your actual anchor you would do the following:

```
<a href="/path/to/image" onclick="printme(event);">Print</a>
```

Comment: This would break - leave page to go to /path/to/image.

Comment: @Kon Ah yes, sorry about that. Adding `return false;` to the end of the function should fix that.

Comment: @musicinmyheadThis opens my image in new window, however it doesnt auto prompt to print like the previous code did. Any fix?

Comment: I've added the return false, however it still does not prompt for print once the new window is opened. :-\ any ideas?

Comment: Sorry. It has now prompted me to print. However, once printed, it's not auto closing the window anymore like it used to. Thanks so far for your assistances! Any idea on the close not working?